# Invoke-command returns inconsistent values

Tags: powershell, foreach, invoke-command

I don't understand why this won't work and if someone could explain better for me?

What I want to do is check winmgmt on all servers but it doesn't seem to work with invoke-command because the script runs so quickly, compared to the half minute/minute it takes when logged into an individual server, and more importantly returns inconsistent values.

So my Powershell script:

```
$list = "serverA", "serverB", "serverC"

foreach ($machine in $list) { invoke-command -computername $machine -command { winmgmt /verifyrepository } }
```

So the script may return serverA as "Inconsistent" yet if I actually log into the server and run winmgmt then serverA might return "Consistent".

There's got to be something small I am missing but not 100% sure now. I looked on different articles and someone said to not run `invoke-command` in a `foreach` but that didn't help.

I tried `-scriptblock` instead of `-command` but that didn't work either.

Comment: I would run it this way in parallel but it shouldn't make a difference:  `invoke-command -computername $list -scriptblock { winmgmt /verifyrepository }`.  There's no "-command" option in invoke-command.

Comment: @js2010: `-Command` is an alias of `-ScriptBock`

Comment: Similar question here suggests wmidiag instead https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/78d69ac9-2bc2-4526-8df6-94ccc093dd5f/powershell-inconsistency-invokecommand-w-quotwinmgmt-verifyrepositoryquot?forum=ITCG